# "Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'checked')" error occuring in just 1 particullar box

Tags: javascript

```js
var all = 0;
var x;

function check(a) {
  x = a;
  // console.log(x);
  var z = document.getElementsByClassName('cb')[x - 1];
  if (x == 1 || x == 10 || x == 91 || x == 100) {
    if (z.checked) {
      all++;
      console.log(all);
    } else {
      all--;
      console.log(all);
    }
  }
  row();
}

function row() {
  // console.log(x);
  var z = document.getElementsByClassName('cb')[x - 1];
  // console.log(z);
  if (x >= 1 && x <= 10) {
    if (z.checked) {
      for (var i = x - 1; i <= 100;) {
        var j = document.getElementsByClassName('cb')[i];
        if (j.checked == false) {
          console.log(!j.checked);
          j.checked = true;
          if (i == 0 || i == 9 || i == 90 || i == 99) {
            console.log(i);
            all++;
          }
        }
        i = i + 10;
      }
    } else {
      for (var i = x - 1; i <= 100;) {
        var j = document.getElementsByClassName('cb')[i];
        if (j.checked) {
          document.getElementsByClassName('cb')[i].checked = false;
          if (i == 0 || i == 9 || i == 90 || i == 99) {
            all--;
          }
        }
        i = i + 10;
      }
    }
  }
  console.log(all);
  full();
}

function full() {
  if (all == 4) {
    // console.log('con true');
    for (var i = 0; i <= 99; i++) {
      // console.log('loop true');
      var y = document.getElementsByClassName('cb')[i];
      if (!y.checked) {
        // console.log('con true');
        document.getElementsByClassName('cb')[i].checked = true;
      }
    }
    all = 0;
  }
  if (all == (-1)) {
    // console.log('con true');
    for (var i = 0; i <= 99; i++) {
      // console.log('loop true');
      var y = document.getElementsByClassName('cb')[i];
      document.getElementsByClassName('cb')[i].checked = false;
    }
    all = 0;
  }
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <div class="flex align around">
    <input type="checkbox" class="cb" onchange="check(1);" name="">
    <input type="checkbox" class="cb" onchange="check(2);" name="">
    <input type="checkbox" class="cb" onchange="check(3);" name="">
    <input type="checkbox" class="cb" onchange="check(4);" name="">
    <input type="checkbox" class="cb" onchange="check(5);" name="">
    <input type="checkbox" class="cb" onchange="check(6);" name="">
    <input type="checkbox" class="cb" onchange="check(7);" name="">
    <input type="checkbox" class="cb" onchange="check(8);" name="">
    <input type="checkbox" class="cb" onchange="check(9);" name="">
    <input type="checkbox" class="cb" onchange="check(10);" name="">
  </div>
  <div class="flex align around">
    <input type="checkbox" class="cb" onchange="check(11);" name="">
    <input type="checkbox" class="cb" onchange="check(12);" name="">
    <input type="checkbox" class="cb" onchange="check(13);" name="">
    <input type="checkbox" class="cb" onchange="check(14);" name="">
    <input type="checkbox" class="cb" onchange="check(15);" name="">
    <input type="checkbox" class="cb" onchange="check(16);" name="">
    <input type="checkbox" class="cb" onchange="check(17);" name="">
    <input type="checkbox" class="cb" onchange="check(18);" name="">
    <input type="checkbox" class="cb" onchange="check(19);" name="">
    <input type="checkbox" class="cb" onchange="check(20);" name="">
  </div>
  <div class="flex align around">
    <input type="checkbox" class="cb" onchange="check(21);" name="">
    <input type="checkbox" class="cb" onchange="check(22);" name="">
    <input type="checkbox" class="cb" onchange="check(23);" name="">
    <input type="checkbox" class="cb" onchange="check(24);" name="">
    <input type="checkbox" class="cb" onchange="check(25);" name="">
    <input type="checkbox" class="cb" onchange="check(26);" name="">
    <input type="checkbox" class="cb" onchange="check(27);" name="">
    <input type="checkbox" class="cb" onchange="check(28);" name="">
    <input type="checkbox" class="cb" onchange="check(29);" name="">
    <input type="checkbox" class="cb" onchange="check(30);" name="">
  </div>
  <div class="flex align around">
    <input type="checkbox" class="cb" onchange="check(31);" name="">
    <input type="checkbox" class="cb" onchange="check(32);" name="">
    <input type="checkbox" class="cb" onchange="check(33);" name="">
    <input type="checkbox" class="cb" onchange="check(34);" name="">
    <input type="checkbox" class="cb" onchange="check(35);" name="">
    <input type="checkbox" class="cb" onchange="check(36);" name="">
    <input type="checkbox" class="cb" onchange="check(37);" name="">
    <input type="checkbox" class="cb" onchange="check(38);" name="">
    <input type="checkbox" class="cb" onchange="check(39);" name="">
    <input type="checkbox" class="cb" onchange="check(40);" name="">
  </div>
  <div class="flex align around">
    <input type="checkbox" class="cb" onchange="check(41);" name="">
    <input type="checkbox" class="cb" onchange="check(42);" name="">
    <input type="checkbox" class="cb" onchange="check(43);" name="">
    <input type="checkbox" class="cb" onchange="check(44);" name="">
    <input type="checkbox" class="cb" onchange="check(45);" name="">
    <input type="checkbox" class="cb" onchange="check(46);" name="">
    <input type="checkbox" class="cb" onchange="check(47);" name="">
    <input type="checkbox" class="cb" onchange="check(48);" name="">
    <input type="checkbox" class="cb" onchange="check(49);" name="">
    <input type="checkbox" class="cb" onchange="check(50);" name="">
  </div>
  <div class="flex align around">
    <input type="checkbox" class="cb" onchange="check(51);" name="">
    <input type="checkbox" class="cb" onchange="check(52);" name="">
    <input type="checkbox" class="cb" onchange="check(53);" name="">
    <input type="checkbox" class="cb" onchange="check(54);" name="">
    <input type="checkbox" class="cb" onchange="check(55);" name="">
    <input type="checkbox" class="cb" onchange="check(56);" name="">
    <input type="checkbox" class="cb" onchange="check(57);" name="">
    <input type="checkbox" class="cb" onchange="check(58);" name="">
    <input type="checkbox" class="cb" onchange="check(59);" name="">
    <input type="checkbox" class="cb" onchange="check(60);" name="">
  </div>
  <div class="flex align around">
    <input type="checkbox" class="cb" onchange="check(61);" name="">
    <input type="checkbox" class="cb" onchange="check(62);" name="">
    <input type="checkbox" class="cb" onchange="check(63);" name="">
    <input type="checkbox" class="cb" onchange="check(64);" name="">
    <input type="checkbox" class="cb" onchange="check(65);" name="">
    <input type="checkbox" class="cb" onchange="check(66);" name="">
    <input type="checkbox" class="cb" onchange="check(67);" name="">
    <input type="checkbox" class="cb" onchange="check(68);" name="">
    <input type="checkbox" class="cb" onchange="check(69);" name="">
    <input type="checkbox" class="cb" onchange="check(70);" name="">
  </div>
  <div class="flex align around">
    <input type="checkbox" class="cb" onchange="check(71);" name="">
    <input type="checkbox" class="cb" onchange="check(72);" name="">
    <input type="checkbox" class="cb" onchange="check(73);" name="">
    <input type="checkbox" class="cb" onchange="check(74);" name="">
    <input type="checkbox" class="cb" onchange="check(75);" name="">
    <input type="checkbox" class="cb" onchange="check(76);" name="">
    <input type="checkbox" class="cb" onchange="check(77);" name="">
    <input type="checkbox" class="cb" onchange="check(78);" name="">
    <input type="checkbox" class="cb" onchange="check(79);" name="">
    <input type="checkbox" class="cb" onchange="check(80);" name="">
  </div>
  <div class="flex align around">
    <input type="checkbox" class="cb" onchange="check(81);" name="">
    <input type="checkbox" class="cb" onchange="check(82);" name="">
    <input type="checkbox" class="cb" onchange="check(83);" name="">
    <input type="checkbox" class="cb" onchange="check(84);" name="">
    <input type="checkbox" class="cb" onchange="check(85);" name="">
    <input type="checkbox" class="cb" onchange="check(86);" name="">
    <input type="checkbox" class="cb" onchange="check(87);" name="">
    <input type="checkbox" class="cb" onchange="check(88);" name="">
    <input type="checkbox" class="cb" onchange="check(89);" name="">
    <input type="checkbox" class="cb" onchange="check(90);" name="">
  </div>
  <div class="flex align around">
    <input type="checkbox" class="cb" onchange="check(91);" name="">
    <input type="checkbox" class="cb" onchange="check(92);" name="">
    <input type="checkbox" class="cb" onchange="check(93);" name="">
    <input type="checkbox" class="cb" onchange="check(94);" name="">
    <input type="checkbox" class="cb" onchange="check(95);" name="">
    <input type="checkbox" class="cb" onchange="check(96);" name="">
    <input type="checkbox" class="cb" onchange="check(97);" name="">
    <input type="checkbox" class="cb" onchange="check(98);" name="">
    <input type="checkbox" class="cb" onchange="check(99);" name="">
    <input type="checkbox" class="cb" onchange="check(100);" name="">
  </div>
</div>
```

// ERROR

Task-8.html:43 Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'checked')
at row (Task-8.html:43:13)
at check (Task-8.html:29:4)
at HTMLInputElement.onchange (Task-8.html:110:66)

// Description
This error is occuring in just first box.Everything else works fine.
The task is to check all boxes when all 4 corners are checked and uncheck all boxes if any 1 corner is unchecked.
And in addition if any of 1 to 10 boxes are checked, than the column containing that box will get checked, And unchecked if we uncheck the box again.

[code pg-1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/P0p99.png)

[code pg-2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/63a94.png)

[code pg-3](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ftKa9.png)

[ERRORE pg](https://i.stack.imgur.com/jYkcO.png)

Comment: Do some debugging to track the value of `x`. Even just logging `x` before you attempt to use it will show you were your problems are

Comment: You're doing an awful lot of querying the DOM for the same set of elements and the same index in that set. You could much more simply use `onchange="check(this)` to pass a reference to the checkbox element

Comment: Please trim your code to make it easier to find your problem. Follow these guidelines to create a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The code is a bit chaotic at first (I don't know if I'm making myself understood ). 
I was curious, so after some testing, the error seems to be in the `for` of the `row function`.

In the condition you evaluate for each loop:

```
// ❌ `i` should never be equal to 100, since we don't have 101 elements
for (var i = x - 1; i <= 100;) {
  i = i + 10
}

// ✅ `i` will always be in the range 0 - 99, which is adequate for our 100 elements
for (let i = x - 1; i < 100; i += 10) {}
```

This resolves the error shown in the console (which is associated with your question) and keeps the logic of checking all inputs if all 4 corners are checked, any other expected logic was not tested.

Comment: Thank you so much @Brian ,I tried it and it worked, and you also explained why it should work so thanks. I would really appreciate it

Comment: @Vasu8278 It's a pleasure to help, if you consider that the question is resolved mark the answer as accepted, good luck!